# send an email without a mail server, username, password in java

Tags: java, smtp

How can I send an email without requiring a mail server and username:password to a specific for e.g.`myemail@myserver.com` email address? So basically I just have the message and a to-email address.

Is this the correct way to do it?

- find the mail server using dns mx record of the `myserver.com`
- Conncet and send an email using smtp to this address?

if yes, how do I do this in java?

some background info - I have webserver and I want to implement a feedback form to the web app user, the webserver gets this form in a POST request and sends this data to a specific email address

note: there are lots of examples using gmail, but then that needs a username password, I would like to avoid that

answer:https://stackoverflow.com/a/271829/494461

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26300755/send-email-without-authentication-in-java-using-gmail-smtp-server-and-javamail

Answer (score 1):

A smtp server is required in order to send the email. If you find the email server for @myserver.com doing a DNS MX lookup, you'll end connecting to that smtp server. So  a server is required.

This link would help you:
[java dns wx lookup example](http://www.eyeasme.com/Shayne/MAILHOSTS/mailHostsLookup.html)